# Python Class() takes no argument error. I am using Self

Tags: python, class, compiler-errors

I've been going through both Stack and the internet at large but I'm not able to find the issue I'm dealing with. I'm new to Python and I'm learning how classes work. I've written up a very simple class and function to print it to the console.

---

```
class Car():

    def __intit__(self, make, model, year):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year

    def get_descriptive_name(self):
        long_name = str(self.year), + " " + self.make + " " + self.model
        return long_name.title()

my_new_car = Car('Chevy', 'sonic', 2015)

print(my_new_car.get_descriptive_name())
```

---

But when I run the compiler it returns the error Car() takes no arguments. I'm aware of the need for self parameter and I've included them in all the areas I can think of putting one. I've done a lot of experimentation on my end and nothing I try changes it. I was hoping someone could explain this to me or might know of a relevant thread?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You have misspelled `__init__()` (you currently have `__intit__()`).

Comment: mispelled `__init__`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have no `__init__` method that takes the instance arguments as you have mispelled it for `def __intit__(self, make, model, year):`. As a result, when instantiating `my_new_car = Car('Chevy', 'sonic', 2015)`, you are passing arguments to Car that does not expect them

Answer (score 10):

Simple typo:

```
def __intit__(self, make, model, year):
```

should be `__init__`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Car():

    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year

    def get_descriptive_name(self):
        long_name = str(self.year) + " " + self.make + " " + self.model
        return long_name.title()

my_new_car = Car('Chevy', 'sonic', 2015)

print(my_new_car.get_descriptive_name())
```

You have two errors,

1. `def __init__` (like above)
2. `long_name = str(self.year) + " " + self.make + " " + self.model`
   after `str(self.year)` you have unnecessary commas